# Ajax.Beginform Submit invoked twice but not in partial view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

1. I have include the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js file in my _Layout.cshtml file. THIS IS THE ONLY PLACE THIS FILE IS REFERENCED.
2. I have a partial view that uses Ajax.Beginform()
3. I have a view (non-partial) that also uses Ajax.BeginForm()

The Partial View works as expected, the submit is invoked once. 
The non-partial View invokes the submission twice.

The only way I could work around this was to remove the ...ajax.min.js file from the _Layout.cshtml file and place it in the partial view. After doing this both the View and Partial view submit only once.

One of the responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496297/asp-net-ajax-beginform-sends-multiple-requests) suggests not using the ...ajax.min.js file since Ajax.Beginform() will work without it - but that doesn't seem to jive with all other posts.

Any ideas of the proper usage?

Thanks!

** UPDATE **
This is the configuration that does not work:

Scripts in my _Layout.cshtml file:

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.528/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.528/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.528/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/kendo.modernizr.custom.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.web.ext.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")"></script>
```

And here is the Ajax.BeginForm() in my View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess" }))
{
...
}
```

And here is the Ajax.BeginForm() in my partial view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveEfficiencyMetrics", "Plan",
                    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "result", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace },
                    new { target = "_self", id = "_SpaceEfficiencyMetrics" }))
    {
    ...
    }
```

Once again, the partial view works, submit is invoked once. however, the main view submit is invoked twice.

I have verified that I am not referencing the script twice.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895918/mvc5-ajax-beginform-and-the-correct-scripts-load-order) are the scripts you need for Ajax.BeginForm. Show us some code otherwise we're just guessing about what the problem could be. What's the view and rendered html look like?

Comment: double check that unobtrusive-ajax.js may be included also in the main layout and also in the view in which ajax.beginform is

Comment: Elisan, no, it is not in the view.