# Ajax form begin and success handlers are called successively more times with each submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

[Why does my jquery ajax form submit once on first submit, twice on second submit...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993047/why-does-my-jquery-ajax-form-submit-once-on-first-submit-twice-on-second-submit)

[Form submitted twice after updating from ASP MVC 3 Preview to Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062568/form-submitted-twice-after-updating-from-asp-mvc-3-preview-to-beta)

[ASP.NET AJAX.BeginForm sends multiple requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496297/asp-net-ajax-beginform-sends-multiple-requests)

My form has OnBegin and OnSuccess handlers as shown below.  The first time I submit it works fine.  The second time I submit OnBegin and OnSuccess are called twice.  The third time the event handlers are called three times, and so on.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveTaxpayer", "Taxpayer",
    null,
    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnBegin = "SaveTaxpayerBegin", OnSuccess = "SaveTaxpayerSuccess", OnFailure = "radarApp.formSubmitFailure" },
    new { id="tpForm", style = "form-horizontal" }))
{...}
```

I've found several posts on SO that describe a similar problem and it turns out the developer was loadng jquery-unobtrusive multiple times.  I am not loading jquery multiple times.  I beleive if I were the event handlers would fire twice every time. I am only loading jQuery in my layout page and that page is called once.

I've also found a post where the answerer suggests

```
$("#myform").unbind('submit');
```

This does not work for me when placed in OnBegin, OnSuccess, or both.

Several posters have faced a similar problem and resolved it returning PartialView versus View.  I am returning a Json object so I dont think that is my problem either.

I've removed all code from my form event handlers for debugging:

```
function SaveTaxpayerBegin() {
    debugger;
}

function SaveTaxpayerSuccess(response) {
    debugger;
    $.get(response.RedirectURL, function (data) { $('#content').empty().html(data); }, 'html');
}
```

My controller returns a simple Json object with a string property that should be self evident: RedirectURL.

'#content' is a div in index.cshtml that is the content div for all partial pages in my single page application.  The page that hosts my form is called using the same $.get... that you see in the  SaveTaxpayerSuccess function above.  This is why this problem is so confusing for me.  The content div is completely blown away every time my page is loaded.  It appears jquery or some javascript class is holding on to the form submit event handlers.

Note also that I am calling .empty() in my $.get success handler (AND in the page that loads my form).  The jquery documentation for .empty() says "To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from the child elements before removing the elements themselves."  This does not appear to be happening.

Comment: when #tpForm is clicked can you unbind the click for #tpForm and then return true? Should let you through and clear it out on the way.

Comment: @mwwallace8  Not sure by what you mean by clicked.  I have two inputs of type "submit" and they have no click handlers.

Comment: @mwwallace8 You put a thought in my head so I named my submit buttons and then tried $("#btn1").unbind(); to clear the event handlers but it does not work. Thank you for pointing me in that direction however.

Comment: yeah that is what i meant.. i think i misunderstood where you were at initially. At some point those buttons being clicked trigger the ajax.. i thought playing with the binding of them might help. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You have added jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js three times. It had happened to me as well.

Check in bundle config "**~/ui/js/jquery.unobtrusive.***" and in your page you have added jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js again